# Variable in NSTask - Objective-C Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstask

I want to use command line in Cocoa for record of the password in a bunch of keys.
But I can't insert a variable at line. How to make it?

How $pass to provide me self.PassKey?

```
self.PassKey = [_PassTextField stringValue];
NSTask *taskPass = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[taskPass setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[taskPass setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"/usr/bin/security delete-generic-password -a ${USER} -s post | security add-generic-password -a ${USER} -s post -w $pass", nil]];
[taskPass launch];
```

Thanks for any help!

Thanks to all for the help and such prompt reply!

So works:

```
self.PassKey = [_PassTextField stringValue];
NSLog(@"text changed: %@", self.PassKey); ///I printed in a window the password 12345

NSString * command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/security delete-generic-password -a ${USER} -s post | security add-generic-password -a ${USER} -s post -w %@", self.PassKey]; ///I receive a line  /usr/bin/security delete-generic-password -a ${USER} -s postftp | security add-generic-password -a ${USER} -s postftp -w 12345
NSLog(@"command line: %@", command);
NSTask *taskPass = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[taskPass setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[taskPass setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", command, nil]];
[taskPass launch];
```

Record of the password in a bunch of keys results.

Comment: I was able to do it with the following lines 8 years ago.  args1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c",command1,nil];
[task1 setArguments:args1];

Comment: Lookup `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:` and use it to compose your command string.

Comment: Many thanks! stringWithFormat: that that solved my problem!